# How is the Apple subscription working with apps?

Tags: ios, subscription

I am planning to make an app on iOS. The app will be free. This app will work without the internet. The app should not be able to query my database if the subscription is not paid.

However the app will still receive "notification" or RSS links even without subscription. The subscription will be monthly minimum.

I did some research but some people are saying it is not possible and some are saying this has been changed by apple and it is now possible.

### Edit

I would like to add that the app will be as much secured as possible. I will have an SQLCypher database inside - so the key will be stored there too (hidden).

Here is the problem that someone told me: The user can use the app only if it paid the monthly/annual subscription, so the key has to be revocable. It seems not compatible with that because the app will have the database deciphered with the key. And if it is deciphered one day, then it will be deciphered next month too.

Answer (score 1):

Why exactly people tell you is not possible?
The only problem I see from what you write is if the free version of your app doesn't do anything. As a general note Apple doesn't allow "demo" versions (even if that concept is not always clear or enforced consistently): a free app must do something not trivial (and of course lots more if the customers pay).

Comment: The free app will be mainly an RSS reader. I mean by that it will deliver articles from a blog. It will show that in notifications for users to read...
However, there will be a database that users will query. That part will be paid only. 
Someone told me that these subscriptions would only work for "ebooks" like magazines ... 
But then I was thinking about Netflix. But netflix is streaming. Not local, so it is different. The same for games like clash of clans...
So you mean it is possible?

Comment: I don't see why they should not approve your app. Anyway if you can query Apple review office directly form your developer account...